# What does $a$ and $b$ leaving equal remainders upon division by $m$ means

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Theorem $3.1.3$**
>
> When $a$ and $b$ are nonnegative integers, the relationship $a\equiv b\text{(mod }m)$ is equivalent to $\underline{\text{$a$ and $b$ leaving equal remainders upon division by $m$}}$
>
> (from UTM "A Readable Introduction to Real Mathmatics" Chapter 3)

---

"is equivalent to $a$ and $b$ leaving equal remainders upon division by $m$"

I'm trying to understand what this means, is it saying:

Let $a,b\ge0$

$a\equiv b\mod m\leftrightarrow (a\equiv s\mod m\wedge b\equiv s\mod m)$, where $s$ is the same remainder

Thanks for your help.

Comment: $ a\equiv b\pmod{\!m}\iff  a \bmod m = b\bmod m\ \ \ $

Comment: Are you assuming that if $s$ is the remainder when $a$ is divided by $m$ that it follows that $a\equiv s \pmod m$ as a given?

Comment: @fleablood I think so

Comment: An analogy: two fractions are equivalent $\iff$ they are equal when reduced to least terms. Generally if you have a way of choosing normal (canonical) reps from equivalence classes then two elements are equivalent iff their normal reps are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means what I think you think it means.

For any $a, b \ge 0$ there are unique integers $j,k,s,t$ so that $a = jm + s; 0\le s < m$ and $b=km + t; 0 \le t < m$.  $t$ and $s$ are called the remainders of $a$ and $b$ respectively.

So that statement is saying:

$a \equiv b \pmod m \iff s =t$.

It's easy to verify.

Pf:  If $a \equiv b \pmod m$ then $m|a-b = (jm + s)-(km+t) = (j-k)m + (s-t)$ so $m|s-t$ but $0\le t< m; 0\le s< m$ so $-m < t-s < m$ so if $m|s-t$ that means $s-t = 0$ and $t=s$.

If $t=s$ then $a-b = (jm+s)-(km+t)= (j-k)m + (s-t) = (j-k)m$.  So $m|a-b$ and $a\equiv b\pmod m$

.....

---

This means you can define $a\equiv b \pmod m$ in two ways.

You can define it as $a\equiv b\pmod m$ if $m|a-b$.

Or

You can define it as $a\equiv b\pmod m$ if $a$ and $b$ have the same remainder when divided by $m$

You can also define it as $a \equiv b\pmod m$ if there is an integer $k$ so that $a = km + b$.

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding is correct. One could think of this with regard to the division algorithm. There exist integers $q_1,q_2$ such that $a=q_1m+s$ and $b=q_2m+s$.

Comment: I also think thinking about it as $m\mid a-b$ is useful.